# String length between 2 numbers java

Tags: java

```
if(symbol.length() < 3)
{
    System.out.print("Error ");
    System.exit(0);
}
else { }
if(symbol.length() > 6)
{
    System.out.print("Error");
    System.exit(0);
}
else { }
```

It should work and the above example works but it is too long, it can be 
shortened and it should be by the example below and the example below compile, but ignores if symbol's length is greater than 6 or smaller than 3.

I was wondering why that works and this doesn't:

```
if(symbol.length() < 3 && symbol.length() > 6)
{
    System.out.print("Error ");
    System.exit(0);
}
else { }
```

Comment: take the time to format your question properly and people will take the time to answer you properly

Comment: If the site is telling you that you need to add more text to submit, it's an indication that **you need to elaborate more**, not that you need to circumvent this rule by adding garbage. -1

Answer (score 4):

If string length is less than 3 it cannot be greater than 6. Instead of `&&` you should use `||`.

```
if(symbol.length() < 3 || symbol.length() > 6) {
    System.out.print("Error ");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: I just realized what a stupid mistake it was, thank you